# Calendar or Planner with support for conditional templates

Tags: windows, linux, calendar, time-management, planning

I would like planner/calendar software which can create checklists for each day based on a set of conditions. For example, every Monday would create a checklist: water plants, strength training, library and then every Tuesday would be cardio training, grocery store, etc.

Ideally there would be full support for logical conditionals, such that I could say something like all 'Mondays that don't fall into a date range' or 'for the next 5 days give the dog his medicine' or '1 month from now change the filter'.

The software can be free or paid, with preference given to open source for either *nix or windows. I am ***NOT*** looking for a mobile or web application. I also do not need reminders or alarms.

Nice to haves are:

- Tracking, so I can see how many consecutive days was something done
- Searching, when was the last time I did something
- Smarter Searching, when was the last time between two dates I did something
- Macros, easy interoperability with the command line, python, JS, or ruby would be nice
- Smart checklist, items not done today are automatically moved to the next day
- Really smart checklist, items not done today are conditionally moved to the next day

I have been using the zim desktop wiki and pasting things in day by day, but I would like something more automatic. I am looking into org-mode, but from what I've read it has a steep learning curve and doesn't necessarily do the calendar stuff smoothly unless you can write your own stuff in emacs-lisp.

Thanks!